# Pass CMD Line Args without WinForm opening - Output to existing CMD Window

Tags: vb.net, winforms, arguments, command-line-arguments

In VB.NET
I have an existing application that uses WMI and Win32 to pull system info, create a salted hash from the gathered info, then display all contents to the user in the WinForm.
I have everything figured out and working.

What I need is the ability to capture command line arguments from CMD ("MyApp.exe /nogui") and output only the salted hash to the user in the existing CMD window, all without showing the WinForm.

I have done everything I can think of...

1. Changing "Application type" to "Console Application". This is undesirable because the console window is shown at all times. (And alters the WinForms theme)
2. I played around with Modules, and couldn't quite figure it out. (I'm not great at module coding, but maybe I'm misunderstanding. idk...)
3. Added `For Each arg As String` and used `Case` to specify the argument ("/nogui") but, the WinForm continued to show.

Please help, thank you!

EDIT: The intention is for Microsoft SCCM to be able to capture the CMD output in a variable.

Comment: *"Title explains it all"*. Even if that were true, there would be no point stating it. It's not true though. Just explain the problem.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for. You say that you don't want to display a form but then you say that one potential solution changes the form theme. Do you want to display one or more forms or not?

Comment: It sounds to me like what you probably want is a WinForms application that doesn't have a startup form. You can then display a form later if and when you want to. [Here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?636812-Formless-Tray-Application) is an example I created of an application that effectively runs in the system tray and you can open a form from the tray icon's menu. Check it out and see if it can do what you want and update your question or add a comment if you need more specific information.

Comment: I don't want the WinForm to be displayed if the exe+arg is called. However, I do want the WinForm to display if you double click. Changing to "Console Application" alters the theme of the WinForm.
EDIT: I can only see this method working if you can prevent 2 things. First the theme change, and second, the console from appearing.

Comment: That makes it clearer. You should update your question and state that explicitly. I probably should have got it from the "/nogui" argument but I didn't actually read what it said, only note that it was there. I've reread your question and can now see what you're saying but it's not completely obvious if you read it quickly and many (most?) people will do. The solution will involve writing your own `Main` method but won't require an `ApplicationContext`. I'll put an answer together.

Comment: I see the mistake, sorry about that. Anything would help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to disable the Application Framework in the project properties. This enables you to write your own `Main` method and have it used as the entry point for the application. You can either add the `Main` method to your existing startup form or you can put it somewhere else, e.g. a `Program` module, and then change the Startup Object in the project properties. You can basically copy what a `Main` method looks like in a C# project as a starting point:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

```vb
<STAThread>
Shared Sub Main()
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)
    Application.Run(New Form1)
End Sub
```

The next step is to read the commandline arguments and display the form or not based on that:

```vb
<STAThread>
Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

    If args.Any(Function(arg) String.Equals(arg, "/nogui", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
        'Display output without GUI.
        Console.WriteLine("Output")
    Else
        'Display GUI.
        Application.Run(New Form1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I have done a case-insensitive comparison to match the commandline argument. That is generally more appropriate but you can make it case-sensitive if you want to.

The problem here is that the `Console.WriteLine` call will not actually write to the existing console window for a WinForms app by default. You need to attach the console window and a bit of reading revealed that you can do that with a Windows API call:

```vb
Private Const ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS As Integer = -1

<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
Private Shared Function AttachConsole(dwProcessid As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

<STAThread>
Public Shared Sub Main(args As String())
    Application.EnableVisualStyles()
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(False)

    If args.Any(Function(arg) String.Equals(arg, "/nogui", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Then
        'Display output without GUI.
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)
        Console.WriteLine("Output")
    Else
        'Display GUI.
        Application.Run(New Form1)
    End If
End Sub
```

I've tested this in a .NET Framework project and it works as expected. I haven't tested it in .NET Core but I believe that it should work the same way.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm at work right now, but I'll test this once I get home.

Comment: Actually, I was able to test it while here at work!
This is a beautiful result! Is there any way to make the console output before CMD asks for the next command? 
 
Current Result: 
C:\Users\admss>C:\TEMP\Args_Test.exe /nogui 
C:\Users\admss>HELLO WORLD! 
 
Desired Result: 
C:\Users\admss>C:\TEMP\Args_Test.exe /nogui 
HELLO WORLD! 
C:\Users\admss>